# How to create a Jaccard Distance Matrix of transactional data?

Tags: python, scipy, transactions, distance, distance-matrix

I am new to programming and this is my first question posted so please have patience with me :) I am trying to create a distance matrix from transactional data so I can do clustering and analyze what products are bought together. I have used pandas.get_dummies to represent transactions as rows and products as columns. The original dataset is quite big with 200 columns and over 300.000 rows. To understand the concept first I am using this test data.

```
data = [[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0], [0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,0,0,1]]

prods = ['Apple', 'Milk', 'Bread', 'Soap']

ids = [345,123,869,567,376]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = prods ,index = ids)
```

I would like the matrix look like this (please ignore the values). 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9AQ3.jpg

I have tryed the scipy pdist function (see code below) but it is calculating the distances for transactions and not the individual products as I would like.

```
res = 1 - pdist(df, 'jaccard')

squareform(res)

distance = pd.DataFrame(squareform(res), index= df.columns, columns=df.columns)
```

Can you please advise me how to create this distance matrix for the products?  Thank you very much!